# NSMutableDictionary issue

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutabledictionary

In my application I take input from user and store it in `NSMutableDictionary` and Fetch result successfully.

But I am little confused about the output print on console. **It's not in an order**.

What is reason behind this output?

Thanks

[image]

I use the following code to store input from textField and print it on Console.

```
-(IBAction)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
 NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstName",@"middleName",@"lastName",@"address",@"email",@"phone",nil];

 DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];  

 obj.personelInfo=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

 for (int a=1; a<=personelInfoCounter; a++) {


    UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:a];




    NSString *fieldValue = textField.text;


    if(fieldValue != nil)
    {
    [obj.personelInfo setObject:fieldValue forKey:[arr objectAtIndex:a-1]];
    }
    else
    {
       [obj.personelInfo setObject:@"" forKey:[arr objectAtIndex:a-1]]; 
    }

}



NSLog(@"Final value of Personal Info Dictionary is ----------------------------------:");

for (id key in obj.personelInfo) {

    NSLog(@"%@      ,      %@", key, [obj.personelInfo objectForKey:key]);

}
}
```

And the output on console is

[image]

Comment: a dictionary is not ordered, i wouldnt expect it to print in any logical order

Comment: @wattson12 thanks. mean every time we run program it may give different order?

Comment: correct, if you rely on an order of values, you will need to sort the keys when accessing the values

Comment: @Prince no, an NSSet is unordered as well, an NSArray is the ordered alternative

Comment: @Gryphon +1 for you. I think question is not bad. but the manner you ask not correct. hope you improve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is not in order. What is reason behind this output?

`NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` don't maintain the order of the things you put in them. It's undefined what order you'll get when you enumerate a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

As wattson said "the dictionary in not ordered". you can make your own logics depending on your key values.

for more info https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html